# Agrupamento e organização de dados no postgres

Tags: postgresql

Estou tentando organizar os dados de duas colunas e exibi-los em uma única célula no meu relatório. A consulta está ok mas estou apanhando pra conseguir organizar os dados no relatório. Segue os dados em questão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando retornar os dados da seguinte forma:
**Ana - 04/07/2022, 05/07/2022, Mercia - 01/07/2022, 07/07/2022, 11/07/2022**

Porém, o máximo que consegui foi retornar assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu SQL:

```
SELECT  c.nome AS substituto,
    
        array_to_string(array_agg(distinct f.nome), ', ') as funcao,
        array_to_string(array_agg(distinct to_char(lc.data_inicio_unidade, 'dd/MM/yyyy')), ', ') as data_inicio_unidade,
        array_to_string(array_agg(distinct lc.mes_lancamento), ', ') as mes_lancamento,
        array_to_string(array_agg(distinct lc.ano_lancamento), ', ') as ano_lancamento,
        array_to_string(array_agg(distinct lc.turno), ', ') as turno,
        array_to_string(array_agg(distinct fh.tipo_lancamento), ', ') as tipo_lancamento,
        sum(fh.hora_substituicao) as h_subs,
        sum(fh.horas_falta) as h_faltas,
        sum(fh.hora_acrescentar) as h_acrescentar,
        array_to_string(array_agg(distinct to_char(fh.data_falta, 'dd/MM/yyyy')), ', ') as data_falta,
        array_to_string(array_agg(distinct un.nome), ', ') as unidade,
        
        array_agg(distinct csub.nome || ' - ' ||  to_char(fh.data_substituicao, 'dd/MM/yyyy')) as substituicoes
    
    FROM faltas_horas_acrescentar_cooperado fh
        left join lancamento_cooperado lc  ON 
         lc.id = fh.lancamento_cooperado_id 
        left join cooperado c ON 
         c.id = lc.cooperado_id 
        left JOIN cooperado csub ON 
         csub.id = fh.cooperado_id 
        left join unidade un ON 
         un.id = lc.unidade_id 
        left join funcao f ON 
         f.id = lc.funcao_id 
    WHERE 
        lc.unidade_id =  $P{ID_UNIDADE} 
        AND
         lc.ano_lancamento =  $P{ANO_LANCAMENTO_COOP} 
         AND 
         lc.mes_lancamento =  $P{MES_LANCAMENTO_COOP} 
         
         group by substituto
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a função 'STRING_AGG' que concatena valores de uma agregação, pois o array_agg ele retorna um array do tipo do parâmetro (argumento) caso o parâmetro  não seja um array, por isso que vem com as chaves.

Exemplo:

```
 STRING_AGG(csub.nome || ' ' ,'-')
```

Fiz outro exemplo, já que não sei exatamente como estão suas tabelas. Mas com esse exemplo acho que você vai entender.

```
CREATE TABLE usuario (
id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
nome varchar(100),
sobrenome varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE email (
id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
id_usuario int NOT NULL,
email varchar(100),
data_criacao timestamp default now()
);

INSERT INTO usuario values(1, 'Joao', 'Alves');
INSERT INTO usuario values(2, 'Joaquim', 'Silva');

INSERT INTO email(id, id_usuario, email) values(1, 1, 'joaoalves1@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO email(id, id_usuario, email) values(2, 1, 'joaoalves2@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO email(id, id_usuario, email) values(3, 2, 'joaquimsilva1@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO email(id, id_usuario, email) values(4, 2, 'joaquimsilva22@gmail.com');
```

**Tabela de Usuario:**

| id | nome | sobrenome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joao | Alves |
| 2 | Joaquim | Silva |

**Tabela de Email:**

| id | id_usuario | email | data_criacao |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | joaoalves1@gmail.com | 2022-08-15 17:43:02 |
| 2 | 1 | joaoalves2@gmail.com | 2022-08-15 17:43:02 |
| 3 | 2 | joaquimsilva1@gmail.com | 2022-08-15 17:43:02 |
| 4 | 2 | joaquimsilva22@gmail.com | 2022-08-15 17:43:02 |

```
select u.nome || ' ' || u.sobrenome as substituto, string_agg(m.id || ' - ' || m.email || to_char(m.data_criacao, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), ', ')  as emails
    from usuario u 
    join email m on(u.id = m.id_usuario)
    group by substituto;
```

E esse é o resultado final que é da mesma forma que você procura, coloquei até um campo com data pra ficar mais parecido.

| substituto | emails |
| --- | --- |
| Joao Alves | 1 - joaoalves1@gmail.com15-08-2022, 2 - joaoalves2@gmail.com15-08-2022 |
| Joaquim Silva | 3 - joaquimsilva1@gmail.com15-08-2022, 4 - joaquimsilva22@gmail.com15-08-2022 |

E ainda você pode usar um ***order by*** no **string_agg**

```
string_agg(m.id || ' - ' || m.email || to_char(m.data_criacao, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), ', ' order by m.email)
```

Comment: Como eu poderia usar o concat para obter aquele resultado? Já tentei de muitas formas o concat também, sozinho, combinado com outras funções, mas sempre aparece mensagens de erro, tipo: **DISTINCT specified, but concat is not an aggregate function**.

Comment: Eu me precipitei na resposta anterior, mas já corrigi, porque na agregação não permite mesmo. O string_agg resolve isso pois ele permite que seja usado com uma ou mais agregações, além de retornar já como string, ai voce não precisa usar o array_to_string.

Comment: Como eu exibiria as duas colunas naquele formato que mencionei ali em cima? **Lembrando que preciso juntar duas colunas.** Seria a pessoa e suas respectivas datas. Ainda não entendi onde coloco a **data_substituicao** pra poder funcionar.

Comment: Individualmente, consigo manipular as colunas. O meu problema está sendo em exibir as duas juntas, conforme exemplo abaixo da primeira imagem.

Comment: Veja se com esse exemplo você consegue agora, já que não sei como estão suas tabelas e as cardinalidades.